# Pandas + scikit-learn - how to apply 2D-array transformations to a DataFrame

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

**Background**

The `scikit-learn` API is based on stateful objects, which take 2D `numpy` arrays as input, compute a transformation (internally, within the object), and later apply it to other 2D arrays. e.g.:

```
arr = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
scaler = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(arr) # scaler state has changed, nothing returns
scaler.transform(arr) # a transformed version of arr returns
```

**My Question**

I want to apply a transformation to data stored in a `pandas` DataFrame, **and put the transformed data back into the same DataFrame.**

The problem is that `df.apply(scaler.transform)` feeds data into the scaler column-by-column (1D arrays), where scaler expects a 2D array.

Following the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813289/keep-pandas-structure-with-numpy-scikit-functions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723472/how-to-use-sklearn-fit-transform-with-pandas-and-return-dataframe-instead-of-num?rq=1), I'm currently doing:

```
transformed_array = scaler.transform(df.values)
transformed_df = pd.DataFrame(data=transformed_array, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

But that seems rather clunky and inefficient. Also, I'm feeling there's a corner case where I'll lose the DataFrame's metadata.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `iloc[:,:]`.

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position)

> Pandas provides a suite of methods in order to get purely integer
>   based indexing. The semantics follow closely python and numpy slicing.
>   These are 0-based indexing. When slicing, the start bounds is
>   included, while the upper bound is excluded. Note that setting works as well.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2.], [3, 4.]], columns=['a', 'b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4.], [5, 6.]], columns=['c', 'd'])

df.iloc[:,:]=df2.values
print(df)
     a    b
0  3.0  4.0
1  5.0  6.0
```

So in your case, it will be:

```
df.iloc[:,:] = scaler.transform(df.values) # On an already fitted scaler
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if assigning like this is more/less efficient than using the constructor? also is iloc better than loc in this sense?

Comment: @OmerB No, I am sorry, I dont know about performance. But `.loc` cannot be used for this, because thats for label-based indexing. In '.loc' you cannot specify index of entries.

Comment: but I can do `.loc[:,:]` or even just `df[:]`... They might be all equivalent, but I'll wait to see if someone has a definitive answer for that...

Comment: @OmerB they are not equivalent perfomance wise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45983830/4016674

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following demo:

```
In [198]: df = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10**5, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))
                  .assign(d=list('abcde')))

In [199]: df
Out[199]:
       a      b      c  d
0  17821  80092  11803  a
1  91198  19663  78665  b
2  77674  46347  72550  c
3  67390  63699  16347  d
4  50445  31346  95608  e

In [200]: cols = ['a','b','c']

In [201]: df[cols] = scaler.fit_transform(df[cols])

In [202]: df
Out[202]:
          a         b         c  d
0 -1.701325  1.466854 -1.259806  a
1  1.196186 -1.315108  0.690414  b
2  0.662151 -0.086660  0.512053  c
3  0.256056  0.712172 -1.127267  d
4 -0.413068 -0.777259  1.184605  e
```